# Creating uniform submit, save, cancel buttons without photoshop

Tags: html, css, forms

Appearance-wise, I am struggling to use CSS to create buttons for forms that will look ok cross-platform and be consistent with each other without using images. Is there such a thing? I just need add/delete/cancel/validate buttons for my form, but I'd like them to be uniform, and ideally work cross platform whether they are submit inputs, buttons, or links.

I really don't want to fiddle in Photoshop though.

I found this resource on [Rediscovering the Button Element (archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/), which shows it can be done with CSS and an image gallery for designers who don't want to create their own.

The solution looks ok, but there are complaints about what IE submits in the postdata in the comments, and about how IE renders the buttons in IE 6.  How can I get around the issues with IE6?

Comment: I believe you can safely ignore IE6, nowadays. Consider that the resource you linked is three years old (which is a fair amount of time, internet-wise), you need to test out how modern browser react to that.

Comment: This IS a practical answerable question about a problem I faced, which is what the FAQ guidelines required. The question was how to have the same appearance cross-platform with consistent post-data which is both specific and answerable. @Kev, closing and downvoting this is inappropriate and heavy-handed as the question fits the FAQ.

Comment: Progressive enhancement. Do your buttons still look like buttons in IE6? Do they work in IE6? Do they look awesome in browsers that have the majority of today's marketshare (Chrome, Firefox, IE9)? Then just use CSS.

Comment: `I believe you can safely ignore IE6` +1

Comment: #ebeland for this question to be useful to future visitors, please edit the following into your post: 1) The CSS that you're trying to create that isn't cross browser (with hacks, if helpful).  Right now your question is just an 'is it possible' question with no real substance to help future visitors; and your question can't stand on its own because when that link changes, the entire background to your question disappears. Once you make those changes, flag the question and we'll be happy to re-open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options, one being color gradients. There is a way to do it in "The Big Three" (Firefox, Chrome/Safari, IE), and you can find a great example [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/).

A second option is to use jQuery UI, and that is a nice way that tends to be cross-browser safe, but the drawback is that it can be a lot to include for buttons.

The last option would be to use images as the background, but that can be a bit tricky in IE, or at least that I've found.